# What is the relation between Android vitals JankStats and firebase total/frozen/slow frames

Tags: android, firebase-performance, android-vitals

I'm trying to send new JankStats performance statics to [firebase performance monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon).

Firebase performance dashboard accepts the following metrics

```
FRAMES_TOTAL("_fr_tot"),
FRAMES_SLOW("_fr_slo"),
FRAMES_FROZEN("_fr_fzn");
```

[image: Firebase metrics]

However, Android Vitals recently delivered [JankStats library](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/jankstats) with the following values.

```
* @param totalFrames The total number of frames (jank and not) since collection
* began (or since the last time the report was issued and reset)
* @param jankFrameData The FrameData for every frame experiencing jank during
```

What is the relation between [JankStatsAggregator] parameters and firebase counterNames (total_frames, frames_slow, frames_frozen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on https://youtu.be/gD8iF0Jildk?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9G2M1W5ztrDvMv-CiFzLM&t=164. Firebase supports now activities and fragment performance metrics automatically